no module named 'adafruit_rgbmatrix'
I am trying to set up an RGB Matrix display using a Raspberry Pi Pico W. I am using: Adafruit CircuitPython 9.1.1 version. But having issues getting the code to work.
While trying to run the below code, I get this error: no module named 'adafruit_rgbmatrix'

import time
import board
import terminalio
import displayio
import random
import rtc
import wifi
import adafruit_ntp
from adafruit_display_text import label
from adafruit_rgbmatrix import rgbmatrix
import framebufferio

# Wi-Fi credentials
SSID = ',,,,,,,'
PASSWORD = ',,,,,,'

# Connect to Wi-Fi
print("Connecting to Wi-Fi...")
wifi.radio.connect(SSID, PASSWORD)
print("Connected to Wi-Fi")

# Set up NTP
ntp = adafruit_ntp.NTP(wifi.radio)
rtc.RTC().datetime = ntp.datetime

# Configuration
bit_depth_value = 6
unit_width = 64
unit_height = 32
chain_width = 1
chain_height = 1
serpentine_value = True

width_value = unit_width * chain_width
height_value = unit_height * chain_height

# Initialize display
displayio.release_displays()
matrix = rgbmatrix.RGBMatrix(
    width=width_value, height=height_value, bit_depth=bit_depth_value,
    rgb_pins=[board.GP2, board.GP3, board.GP4, board.GP5, board.GP8, board.GP9],
    addr_pins=[board.GP10, board.GP16, board.GP18, board.GP20],
    clock_pin=board.GP11, latch_pin=board.GP12, output_enable_pin=board.GP13,
    tile=chain_width, serpentine=serpentine_value, doublebuffer=True
)
DISPLAY = framebufferio.FramebufferDisplay(matrix, auto_refresh=True, rotation=180)

# Create a display group for our screen objects
group = displayio.Group()

# Define colors
colors = [0xFF0000, 0x00FF00, 0x0000FF, 0xFFFF00, 0xFF00FF, 0x00FFFF]
color_index = 0

# Create text label
text_area = label.Label(terminalio.FONT, text="", color=colors[color_index])
group.append(text_area)

# Show group on the display
DISPLAY.show(group)

def get_time():
    current_time = time.localtime()
    return "{:02}:{:02}:{:02}".format(current_time.tm_hour, current_time.tm_min, current_time.tm_sec)

def update_time():
    global color_index
    current_time = get_time()
    text_area.text = current_time
    text_area.color = colors[color_index]
    color_index = (color_index + 1) % len(colors)

xpos = DISPLAY.width
last_color_change = time.monotonic()
last_update = time.monotonic()

while True:
    now = time.monotonic()

    # Update time and color every 4 seconds
    if now - last_color_change > 4:
        update_time()
        last_color_change = now

    # Scroll the text
    text_area.x = xpos
    xpos -= 1
    if xpos < -text_area.bounding_box[2]:
        xpos = DISPLAY.width
        time.sleep(0.5)  # Pause for 1/2 second before scrolling again

    DISPLAY.refresh(minimum_frames_per_second=0)
    time.sleep(0.05)



I cant not find any modules for this. Is my code wrong?
